# How can UI be added to my Django rest API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest

I want to replace this with with custom UI

[image: I want to replace this with with custom UI]

My question is that I have developed a REST API using Django rest framework, when you run the API you get Django's predefined rest framework web UI and the data in JSON in that web UI. How do I add my own User Interface? I am very stuck on this and want to make a dashboard but how do I add the front end code and web design to the JSON coming from Django in the predefined UI.

Comment: did you read it https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes I have but here is the thing I want to confirm, after I make the rest API like shoe in the image I provided will front end developers be able to make that json output into something beautiful using vuejs or angular? Because I am looking to make a dashboard which uses Django rest as back end and angular or vuejs as front end

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#customizing

To customize the default style, create a template called rest_framework/api.html that extends from rest_framework/base.html

```
templates/rest_framework/api.html
{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}
# Override blocks with required customizations
```

...

[Dark Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uROP.png)